# Grabbed Post ID under WP loop, but still couldn't Print Post title

Tags: loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
                            <?php echo '<h1><a>' . get_the_title() . '</a></h1>'; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I used the loop to grab the Post ID, but still the title of that post couldn't be printed on the live website page of that particular post. what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in a Loop, you don't need to grab the post ID or use `get_the_title()`. Instead, replace line 2 and 3 of your code with:

```
the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
```

Or, if you want to include a link as well:

```
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: You are right in a loop we do not need to write this → `get_the_title()`.sorry for making such a silly mistake, but that's how the learning process is. I will remember the difference for the rest of my WP Journey. I am accepting your answer now.

Comment: Please upvote me if you think that this is a good question and may help other in future.